# Just installed nginx and now having bind error - address already in use

Tags: apache, installation, nginx, bind

i am running a vps with apache. 
just installed nginx. got the address already in use error at port 80 because apache is using it. I am new to linux/apache stuff so is it possible to change the port of nginx and how ? if yes will it work as i want it to serve static files automaticaly or should i get my hosting company to do it instead since i don't know much about these.

and yes i used this tutorial to install it http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/installation/centos-5

Help Appreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look either into

- your `nginx.conf` file
- or any of the sites in `sites-enabled` (usually under the `nginx` directory)

and search the `server` part, `listen`

```
  server {
    listen   80;
```

here you can change the port for 81 for instance instead of 80.

Notes:

- you may also have the `server { listen }` part within your `nginx.conf` directly
- if you are under Linux, the configuration is usually in `/etc/nginx` (nginx.conf) and `sites-enabled` is below that directory.
- regarding Apache (Linux), using either `service apache stop` or `service httpd stop` or `/etc/init.d/apache stop` (or httpd) should work to stop the process, or try `killall httpd` or `killall apache` (or apache2) to stop Apache.